# Error - security function no side effects - TradingView pine script

Tags: pine-script, trading

Im writing this to get a variable from 1W timeframe to use in a lower timeframe.

I draw a line with 2 points in history, and then I get the value of line at the current bar.

I draw the line on timeframe 1W, it connects 2 points from the bar_index[2] to the bar_index[1] and so I can get the value of that line at the current bar_index (all 3 bar_index are on 1W timeframe).

```
//@version=4

msma = sma(close, 14)
var msma_line = line.new(bar_index[1], high[1], bar_index, low, extend = extend.right)
line.set_xy1(msma_line, bar_index[2], msma[2])
line.set_xy2(msma_line, bar_index[1], msma[1])
msma_point = line.get_price(msma_line,bar_index)

W_1 =  security(syminfo.tickerid, "1W", msma_point, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Now I get that value (V) at the current week, I go to the timeframe 4H, and I want to see that (V) value, store it in a variable, so I can compare it with the current close.

```
if (close > W_1)
  // here is what to do with the comparaison
```

But I have got the error

> 'expression' argument of security function should have no side effects

What does that mean?

How I can use the W_1 variable at lower timeframe ?

Comment: Please specify, do you want to draw a line on the higher timeframe? What value do you want to get from the higher timeframe?

Comment: I edited my question to explain what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after many tries and failed, I found a way to get the same value of 1W line point on any lower timeframe:

```
msma = sma(close, 14)

[Wmsma, Wmsma_1, Wmsma_2] =  security(syminfo.tickerid, "1W", [msma, msma[1], msma[2]], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

anynumber = 42 // any number >= 42 will work, but because Im on the 4H chart, so I set it == 42, because there are 42 bars of 4H per week
anynumber2 = anynumber + anynumber

var msma_line = line.new(bar_index[1], high[1], bar_index, low, extend = extend.right)
line.set_xy1(msma_line, bar_index[anynumber2], Wmsma_2)
line.set_xy2(msma_line, bar_index[anynumber], Wmsma_1)
msma_point = line.get_price(msma_line,bar_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that msma is being generated on the lower timeframe, using this should solve the problem

```
msma = security(syminfo.tickerid,"1w",sma(close, 14))
var msma_line = line.new(bar_index[1], high[1], bar_index, low, extend = extend.right)
line.set_xy1(msma_line, bar_index[2], msma[2])
line.set_xy2(msma_line, bar_index[1], msma[1])
msma_point = line.get_price(msma_line,bar_index)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It's still showing the same error.

Comment: Once you use my line, you don't need the last line anymore, let me update the answer for you..

Comment: I appreciate your help but it's not working as expected. Because the bar_index[2] IS NOT the bar of 2 weeks ago, but it's the bar of 2 *4H ago, if I check on the timeframe 4H

Comment: Well, of course its going to be that way. In calculating  the 'msma_line', you haven't mentioned to take weekly charts, how will the pine script know what timeframe to take ? So it takes the one with the chart resolution

Comment: My advise. get the high and low of weekly candle, store them in a avriable and then plot a line

Comment: I edited my question to provide more info about my need